# call function during xml traversal in groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, markupbuilder

I transform one xml to another and I am not able to call function defined on script level from closure which used to process node from input xml.
See example code

```
def xml = new MarkupBuilder()

def text ='''
<x>
    <y id='1'/>
    <y id='2'/>
</x>
'''
def x = new XmlSlurper().parseText(text)

String generateId(String s) {
// some code 
}

xml.root() {
    x.y.each {
        a(id: generateId(it.@id))
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<root>
  <generateId>1</generateId>
  <a id='generateId' />
  <generateId>2</generateId>
  <a id='generateId' />
</root>
```

As you can see function `generateId()` is not called but node with name generateId is written to output xml.

I suppose it is MarkupBuilder which steps in and handles call but how can I walk around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the `text()` of the `id` attribute:

```
String generateId(String s) {
    'generated ' + s
}

xml.root() {
    x.y.each {
        a(id: generateId(it.@id.text()))
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks. I didn't notice that the type of it.@id is not String but groovy.util.slurpersupport.Attributes.